# Taking a user's input string and splitting it in Java

Tags: java, string, split, java.util.scanner

I want to take the input from a user, in this case, their full name and split it with the .split(" ") command into 2 or 3 sections, depending on number of names, and then print out the results on different lines:

For example,

User inputs:

"John Doe Smith"

Program returns:

John

Doe

Smith

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
        name = input.next();
        String[] parts = name.split(" ");
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(parts));

    }
}
```

This currently only returns the first part of the name.

The program should also be able to deal with someone not having a middle name.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I print this to different lines?

Comment: Loop over the `parts` array
      `for(String part : parts ){
System.out.println(part);
}`

Comment: What about making it so it can deal with 2 names and not 3?

Comment: It will work, no matter how much tokens you have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input.next()` returns only the first string before the first encountered blank space, try `input.nextLine()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            name = input.next();
            String[] parts = name.split(" ");
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(parts));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [JavaDoc of Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()), the next() method returns the next token of your input stream. Not the entire line.

Comment: This describes the problem, not the solution

Answer (score 0):

This would also work, maybe.

Executed as e.g. java -jar SplitTest.jar Something Null

```
public class SplitTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String name = "";
  for (String arg : args) {
   name = arg;
   System.out.println(name);
  }
 }
}
```